# Firebase Functions : How to wait for a promise before exporting function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to tie an express app to a firebase https function, and I need to support swagger docs, and routing with swagger as well, but for routing I need to wait for setup to finish before exporting. I tried this with no luck.

```
async function initApp() {
    const config = {
        appRoot: __dirname
    };

const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
main.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc));

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    SwaggerExpress.create(config, (err: any, swaggerExpress: any) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

        swaggerExpress.register(main);
        resolve();
    });
});

return main;
}


export const api = initApp().then(main => functions.https.onRequest(main));
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to export a function from a module after some promise has resolved.  The export needs to be defined at compile time.  I don't know how swagger works, but in any event, you will need to export a statically defined function, and make use of async promises only within the runtime execution of your function.  Otherwise, the Firebase CLI will not know that you have a function to deploy.

Comment: Thank you, can you please add an example based on my code snippet.

Comment: An example of something different than you see in the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Ok, this doesn't answer my question. As you can see, I'm trying to wait for some task to complete, before exporting a firebase function. That's the solution I need, and since I can only assign a function by exporting it, this isn't helping.

Comment: I'm saying you can't do that. JavaScript simply doesn't allow it.

Comment: If there was a way to start a function without exporting it this way, this would be a Javascript issue, really. So you're telling me I can't start a function before doing any async work?

Comment: That's correct. The async work has to be dealt with inside the cloud function declaration callback, after it has deployed and begun execution.

Comment: Well, that's terrible to hear.

Comment: Again, it's the way JavaScript works.  All those exports need to be immediately available upon require/import.  The engine isn't going to wait around for some promise to resolve in order to make exports available to the caller. That would be terrible for the code doing the import.